# problemas con mi carrusel en Hubspot con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con Hubspot, en mi module.js estoy armando un carrusel, el mismo tiene elementos activos que se desplazan de a uno de acuerdo a la flecha que hacemos clic, mi problema esta en que cuando se desplaza a la derecha no llega al final del carrusel, se desplaza hasta el index 3 y queda trabado, nose como sulucionarlo

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const carousels = $(".bzb-wrap-1");

  carousels.each(function () {
    const carousel = $(this);
    const carouselWrapper = carousel.find(".bzb-wrap-2");
    const carouselItems = carouselWrapper.find(".bzb-wrap-square-1");
    const itemWidth = carouselItems.eq(0).outerWidth();
    const carouselWidth = carouselWrapper.width();
    const numVisibleItems = 3; 
    const totalItems = carouselItems.length;
  

    // Función para establecer el elemento activo y desplazar de a uno
    function setActiveItem() {
  const scrollLeft = carouselWrapper.scrollLeft();
  console.log("Scroll Left:", scrollLeft);

  const newIndex = Math.round(scrollLeft / itemWidth);
  console.log("New Index:", newIndex);

  carouselItems.removeClass("active").find('.bzb-text-1, .bzb-text-2').removeClass('active');
  carouselItems.eq(newIndex).addClass("active").find('.bzb-text-1, .bzb-text-2').addClass('active');

  // Desactivar la flecha izquierda si estamos en el primer elemento
  carousel.find(".bzb-arrow-wrap-left-1").toggleClass("disabled", newIndex === 0);

  // Desactivar la flecha derecha si estamos en el último elemento
  const lastIndex = totalItems - numVisibleItems;
  console.log("Last Index:", lastIndex);
  carousel.find(".bzb-arrow-wrap-right-1").toggleClass("disabled", newIndex >= lastIndex);

  currentIndex = newIndex;

  console.log("Current Index:", currentIndex);
}


    // Evento para mover hacia la izquierda
    carousel.find(".bzb-arrow-wrap-left-1").on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (currentIndex > 0) {
        const newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        const scrollLeft = newIndex * itemWidth;
        carouselWrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft }, 400, function () {
          setActiveItem();
        });
      }
    });

    // Evento para mover hacia la derecha
    carousel.find(".bzb-arrow-wrap-right-1").on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const lastIndex = totalItems - numVisibleItems;
      if (currentIndex < totalItems -1) {
        const newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        const scrollLeft = newIndex * itemWidth;
        carouselWrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft }, 400, function () {
          setActiveItem();
        });
        } else {
    // Si estamos en el último índice, desplazamos hasta el final del carrusel
    const scrollLeft = lastIndex * itemWidth;
    carouselWrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft }, 400, function () {
      setActiveItem();
    });
  }
});

    // Llamadas a la función setActiveItem para inicializar el estado del carrusel
    setActiveItem();

    // Establecer el desplazamiento inicial
    carouselWrapper.scrollLeft(currentIndex * itemWidth);

    // Actualizar el elemento activo al hacer scroll
    carouselWrapper.on("scroll", setActiveItem);
  });
});
```

Contexto:
El código anterior es parte de un script en JavaScript que se encarga de gestionar un carrusel en una página web. El carrusel está compuesto por una serie de elementos que se desplazan de uno en uno al hacer clic en las flechas de navegación.

Detalles Adicionales:

El carrusel está contenido dentro de un elemento con la clase .bzb-wrap-1.
Utilizo jQuery para manejar los eventos de clic en las flechas de navegación (bzb-arrow-wrap-left-1 y bzb-arrow-wrap-right-1) y para realizar animaciones de desplazamiento.
El problema parece estar relacionado con el cálculo del índice al desplazarse hacia la derecha, ya que el carrusel se detiene en el índice 3 y no llega al final.

Comment: Hola, deberias de agregar tu HTML